# Angular 5 common.js:263 Uncaught ReferenceError: $st is not defined

Tags: angular5

Tengo un problema con Angular 5, el proyecto funciona con normalidad pero después de un tiempo sale este error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se la razón de este error, yo no he tocado ese archivo, aunque el error no interfiere en el funcionamiento de la aplicación siempre es molesto que aparezca.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Jhon, haz el [**_Recorrido_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y consigue tu primer medalla. Por otro lado es muy recomendable no poner imágenes del código, ni de los errores, cuando pueden ser puestos en formato de texto. Recuerda pasar tambien por [**_¿Como Preguntar?_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ese archivo es parte del *core* de angular. Hay algo en tu código que falla, deberías comprobar cuando esa línea se ejecuta desde donde llega

Comment: Me pasa igual tengo el mismo error que se observa por consola, pero todo funciona correctamente al momento de correrlo , ni idea porque ese error y es bien molesto que aparezca siempre al observar la consola

Comment: Ya revise y no importa en que vista este, siempre sale ese error después de un tiempo como 2 minutos

Comment: En lugar de regañar a los usuarios por hacer preguntas de forma incorrecta y cerrarlas, deberíamos intentar ayudarlas.

La pregunta del usuario es perfectamente válida.

No importa si el texto o las imágenes se usan para explicar.

Regañar a los usuarios y cerrarlos no ayuda a construir la comunidad.